# JMeter how to confirm the max throughput?

Tags: java, jmeter

These days I am trying to use JMeter to do load test. There is a very confusing point I can't understand:
The distributed environments:
1. Three 8 CPUs 16G servers running JMeter Server
2. 4 CPUs 8G server running JMeter
3. These servers are on the same subnet.

The Thread Group settings: 
Threads number: 2000
Ramp-up: 0
Loop: 10
The Throughput is 3000/s

and another Thread Group:
Threads number: 2000
Ramp-up: 1
Loop: 10
The Throughput is 5000/s

and another Thread Group:
Threads number: 2000
Ramp-up: 1
Loop: 5
The Throughput is 4000/s

So, I have no idea which one is the right Throughput, or should I have to try different number, ramp-up, loop to get the highest Throughput? Or I am wrong, someone help, it's very confusing?

Comment: Actually Ramp up 0 is not real scenario , 2000 users/requests do not come in 0/1 second if we imagine , you should create some feasible test plan and then you can check everything based on that.

Answer (score 2):

To load tests I'd recommend ThoughoutputShaper plugin (from http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/).

It provides intuitive interface to experiment with TPS/RPS and is very efficient when it comes to generate required load.